# MongoDB counts multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

Here is the input collection :

```
{"itemName" : "A1", "voteType" : "up"}
{"itemName" : "A1", "voteType" : "up"}
{"itemName" : "A1", "voteType" : "down"}
{"itemName" : "A2", "voteType" : "up"}
{"itemName" : "A2", "voteType" : "down"}
{"itemName" : "A2", "voteType" : "down"}
{"itemName" : "A2", "voteType" : "down"}
and so on...
```

Does anyone know how to get the following documents with Aggregation?

Also, how can we use Spring Data to implement this?

```
{ "id" : "A1", "CountUp" : 2, "CountDown" : 1}
{ "id" : "A2", "CountUp" : 1, "CountDown" : 3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work.
The `$cond` operator can be used to populate the `CountUp` and `CountDown` fields. After that its just grouping the data

```
     {
         $project:
           {
             itemName: 1,
             countUp:
               {
                 $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$voteType", "up" ] }, 1, 0 ]
               },
               countdown:
               {
                 $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$voteType", "down" ] }, 1, 0 ]
               }
           }
      },

     { $group : { _id : "$itemName", countUp: { $sum: "$countUp" }, countDown: { $sum: "$countdown" } }}
```